# Update on observable array foreach removes formatting knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Updating an observable array that is linked to a foreach will redraw all the DOM elements the forEach generates. Without tying observable elements to properties of the objects in the array, is there a way to avoid the complete redraw of the DOM?

I obviously want the particular elements redrawn that are updated, but if I have a hidden/visible element it will reset it to the default (if it's a JS onclick styled piece).

http://jsfiddle.net/OrganicCat/CjH87/6/

```
var SimpleListModel = function(items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    this.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");

    this.openItem = function(data, event) {
        $(event.target).next().toggle();
    };
    this.modifyList = function() {
        var modifiedList = ["Cats", "Dogs", "Hedgehogs"];
        this.items(modifiedList);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new SimpleListModel(["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"]));
```

Comment: are you adding/removing elements from the array?  Or just updating properties of the items?

Comment: Updating properties of items in the array

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at your architecture a bit.

MVVM means your entire view should be bound to your viewModel. So all elements are controlled by the view model.

If you try and do a half and half approach then you'll find yourself fighting the MVVM pattern. If you need to control the visibility of elements that are part of a foreach you need to control visibility from your observable array.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm altering an array that has some very large complex objects in it. It's relatively easier to actually do a array.map on the observable array, which unfortunately redraws the foreach section it is bound to. Overall, I don't understand why updating the array has to redraw the visibility of the DOM elements just because the data the array was bound to changes. I could understand if the number of array elements changes, but that is not the case.

Comment: Hi,Do you have a JSFiddle of what you are trying to do?
RE: UI Redrawing when data changes this is kind of the point of the MVVM architecture. i.e. Changes to data are reflected in the UI.

Comment: Yes: http://jsfiddle.net/OrganicCat/CjH87/6/

Click on one of the elements, then "Modify List". You'll see the elements reset their visibility.